# c# worksheet.Activate() does not work

Tags: c#, excel

Anyone has an idea why this does not activate the sheet in c#?

```
excelApp.excelWorkbook.Sheets["Kbc nyesz"].Activate();
```

The file is saved properly in c# but when I open it in excel, another sheet is active. There was no error or exception when the Active() was executed. The Visible property of the sheet is set to Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible.

Answer (score 0):

I saved the file with sheet1.Save() where sheet1 is Worksheet. This made sheet1 active, so overwritten the previous Activate(). When I tried workbook.Save() there was no such probelm.